# Split comma delimited names in Microsoft Report Builder

Tags: sql, sql-server, split, report, builder

In my database, I have a column, which lists names.  Names are in this format:

surname, first name, surname, first name

e.g:  bloggs, joe, jackson, samuel

I'm assuming I will use a 'split' expression, but how do I write it so that it appears in my report as:

surname, first name
surname, first name

Thanks

Comment: edit:  surname, first name and then the next name is split to the next line

Comment: You can edit the question.

Comment: _Names are in this format_ Why? Fix your schema and use a properly normalized design and you will reduce the cost of your system greatly over its lifetime. Absent that, you seem to know you need to split your string so give it a try. String splitting is the most common question on SO and simple searching will find thousands (millions?) of similar questions.

Comment: The reason you are struggling with this query is because you have violated 1NF by storing multiple values in a single tuple. Fix your design and your query will be easy.

Answer (score 1):

test table

```
declare @t table(ch varchar(max))
insert into @t values('bloggs, joe, jackson, samuel')
```

your query PARSENAME(REPLACE) divide your table into columns based on character after **,** like

```
SELECT  
PARSENAME(REPLACE(ch,',','.'),4) 'Surname1' ,
PARSENAME(REPLACE(ch,',','.'),3) 'FirstName1',
PARSENAME(REPLACE(ch,',','.'),2) 'Surname2',
PARSENAME(REPLACE(ch,',','.'),1) 'FirstName2'
FROM @t
```

then use union in order to put it in columns, or concat to put your value in a single column.

```
SELECT  
concat(
PARSENAME(REPLACE(ch,',','.'),4),',',
PARSENAME(REPLACE(ch,',','.'),3) )'Names'
FROM @t
UNION all
SELECT 
concat(
PARSENAME(REPLACE(ch,',','.'),2),',',
PARSENAME(REPLACE(ch,',','.'),1) )'Names'
from @t
```

if your column has more than two name then use updated syntax with descending order

```
------------(K) Ordered Pair--------------
SELECT  
concat(
PARSENAME(REPLACE(ch,',','.'),2K),',',
PARSENAME(REPLACE(ch,',','.'),2K-1) )'Names'
FROM @t
UNION all
------------(K-1) Ordered Pair-------------
SELECT 
concat(
PARSENAME(REPLACE(ch,',','.'),2K-2),',',
PARSENAME(REPLACE(ch,',','.'),2K-3) )'Names'
from @t 
/*--------------------------------------*/
/*--------------------------------------*/
/*--------------------------------------*/
------------(2) Ordered Pair--------------
SELECT  
concat(
PARSENAME(REPLACE(ch,',','.'),4),',',
PARSENAME(REPLACE(ch,',','.'),3) )'Names'
FROM @t
UNION all
------------(1) Ordered Pair--------------
SELECT 
concat(
PARSENAME(REPLACE(ch,',','.'),2),',',
PARSENAME(REPLACE(ch,',','.'),1) )'Names'
from @t
```

The other-way is using string_split to split charchter,NTILE to give it rank and string_agg to results into one column that enables you to have more than 2 names

```
select string_agg(value,',') from
(
SELECT 
value , NTILE (2) OVER (
ORDER BY value
) ID 
FROM @t
cross apply
STRING_SPLIT(ch, ',')) t
group by ID
```

Comment: This works if, and only if, the actual data contains no more than 2 names. I highly doubt that is the case. Given that, this answer is really not a good solution to this problem.

Comment: More parsename and more union would work but is far less than ideal. A string splitter would be more appropriate.

Comment: That is a better path. Of course the ideal path would be that the OP fixes their data structure.

Comment: thanks for your mentions that gives better results